# HTML / CSS gets messed up due to JS - how to fade in letter by letter without destroying formatting

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadein

I would like to fade in a website letter by letter - but JS seems to mess up the formatting - can you tell what the error is in this code (see below) - i deployed the current version here - http://digitale-anamnese.com/results2.html - there you can see the problem.

Cheers,
Florian

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ihre Ergebnisse</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .results-container {
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            max-width: 800px;
            margin: 40px auto;
        }

        h1, h3 {
            color: #333;
        }

        p, ul {
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 1.6;
            color: #666;
        }

        a {
            color: #3498db;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        li {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .highlight {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const container = document.querySelector('.results-container');
            const originalHTML = container.innerHTML;
            container.innerHTML = '';  // Clear the container

            let i = 0;

            function typeCharacter() {
                if (i < originalHTML.length) {
                    if (originalHTML[i] === "<") {
                        // If we encounter an opening tag, add the entire tag at once
                        const closingTagIndex = originalHTML.indexOf(">", i);
                        container.innerHTML += originalHTML.slice(i, closingTagIndex + 1);
                        i = closingTagIndex + 1;
                    } else if (originalHTML[i] === "&") {
                        // Handle HTML entities (like &nbsp;)
                        const entityEndIndex = originalHTML.indexOf(";", i);
                        container.innerHTML += originalHTML.slice(i, entityEndIndex + 1);
                        i = entityEndIndex + 1;
                    } else {
                        container.innerHTML += originalHTML[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                    setTimeout(typeCharacter, 10);  // Adjust this value to control typing speed
                }
            }

            typeCharacter();  // Start the typing effect
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="results-container">
    <h1>Diese Förderungen kommen in Frage</h1>

    <h3>Deutschland-Spezifische Förderungen</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="highlight">Zentrales Innovationsprogramm Mittelstand (ZIM)</span>
            <ul>
                <li><strong>Ziel:</strong> Förderung von Innovationsprojekten</li>
                <li><strong>Förderquote:</strong> Bis zu 45% der förderfähigen Kosten</li>
                <li><strong>Wichtige Kriterien:</strong> Innovationsgrad, Marktpotenzial, technologische Machbarkeit</li>
                <li><strong>Webseite:</strong> <a href="https://www.zim.de/ZIM/Navigation/DE/Home/home.html" target="_blank">ZIM Webseite</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- ... Add other Deutschland-Spezifische Förderungen here ... -->

    </ul>

    <h3>EU-Förderungen</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="highlight">Horizon Europe</span>
            <ul>
                <li><strong>Ziel:</strong> Forschung und Innovation</li>
                <li><strong>Förderquote:</strong> In der Regel bis zu 100% der förderfähigen Kosten</li>
                <li><strong>Wichtige Kriterien:</strong> Wissenschaftliche Exzellenz, gesellschaftliche Relevanz, europäische Zusammenarbeit</li>
                <li><strong>Webseite:</strong> <a href="https://ec.europa.eu/info/horizon-europe_en" target="_blank">Horizon Europe Webseite</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- ... Add other EU-Förderungen here ... -->

    </ul>

    <p>Diese Programme haben unterschiedliche Anforderungen, Fristen und Auswahlverfahren. Es ist daher ratsam, sich gründlich über die einzelnen Programme zu informieren und eventuell eine professionelle Beratung in Anspruch zu nehmen.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what I tried - http://digitale-anamnese.com/results2.html
I expected formatting (h1 tags etc. / list format) to be intact but as you can see it´s kind of messed up.

KR

Comment: That will never work the way you intended. When you add a tag to the browsers DOM, the browser will automatically add the corresponding _closing_ tag as well. That's why your HTML is "messed up" - you loose the nesting because you simply _cannot_ add (for instance) a `<ul>` element _without_ the `</ul>` that belongs to it. The browser itself adds it _automatically as soon as the opening tag is added_ to `.innerHTML`. Test it: Open a fresh page, type `document.body.innerHTML = '<ul>';` and check the result - it _will_ have a closing `</ul>`.

Comment: I didn't look much into how your code works, but from a quick glance and feeling it could be that the browser is auto-closing tags for you therefore you do not get the expected output. You could try to clone your original div, then using recursive approach to fetch all the child nodes and run your typer on the cloned child nodes instead and replace the result on every iteration on the new target div.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.  @RUKAclMortality - that was a great idea - with your suggested approach it works - http://digitale-anamnese.com/results2.html

Answer (score 2):

As @RUKAclMortality pointed out, cloning did the trick :-)

`````
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const container = document.querySelector('.results-container');
            const clonedContainer = container.cloneNode(true); // Clone the container with all its content
            container.innerHTML = '';  // Clear the container

            function typeNode(node, targetContainer) {
                if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    // If it's a text node, type its content character by character
                    let i = 0;
                    function typeCharacter() {
                        if (i < node.nodeValue.length) {
                            targetContainer.append(node.nodeValue[i]);
                            i++;
                            setTimeout(typeCharacter, 10);
                        }
                    }
                    typeCharacter();
                } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    // If it's an element node, clone it without its children
                    const clonedNode = node.cloneNode(false);
                    targetContainer.appendChild(clonedNode);

                    // Recursively type the children of this node
                    let childIndex = 0;
                    function typeChild() {
                        if (childIndex < node.childNodes.length) {
                            typeNode(node.childNodes[childIndex], clonedNode);
                            childIndex++;
                            setTimeout(typeChild, 10);
                        }
                    }
                    typeChild();
                }
            }

            typeNode(clonedContainer, container);
        });
    </script>````
`````

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I am using typed.min.js quite a handy library gives nice typing effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Typing Effect Website</title>
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .results-container {
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 40px auto;
    }

    h1, h3 {
        color: #333;
    }

    p, ul {
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1.6;
        color: #666;
    }

    a {
        color: #3498db;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    li {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .highlight {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="results-container" id="typewriter-content">
    <h1>Diese Förderungen kommen in Frage</h1>

    <h3>Deutschland-Spezifische Förderungen</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="highlight">Zentrales Innovationsprogramm Mittelstand (ZIM)</span>
            <ul>
                <li><strong>Ziel:</strong> Förderung von Innovationsprojekten</li>
                <li><strong>Förderquote:</strong> Bis zu 45% der förderfähigen Kosten</li>
                <li><strong>Wichtige Kriterien:</strong> Innovationsgrad, Marktpotenzial, technologische Machbarkeit</li>
                <li><strong>Webseite:</strong> <a href="https://www.zim.de/ZIM/Navigation/DE/Home/home.html" target="_blank">ZIM Webseite</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- ... Add other Deutschland-Spezifische Förderungen here ... -->

    </ul>

    <h3>EU-Förderungen</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="highlight">Horizon Europe</span>
            <ul>
                <li><strong>Ziel:</strong> Forschung und Innovation</li>
                <li><strong>Förderquote:</strong> In der Regel bis zu 100% der förderfähigen Kosten</li>
                <li><strong>Wichtige Kriterien:</strong> Wissenschaftliche Exzellenz, gesellschaftliche Relevanz, europäische Zusammenarbeit</li>
                <li><strong>Webseite:</strong> <a href="https://ec.europa.eu/info/horizon-europe_en" target="_blank">Horizon Europe Webseite</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- ... Add other EU-Förderungen here ... -->

    </ul>

    <p>Diese Programme haben unterschiedliche Anforderungen, Fristen und Auswahlverfahren. Es ist daher ratsam, sich gründlich über die einzelnen Programme zu informieren und eventuell eine professionelle Beratung in Anspruch zu nehmen.</p>
</div>
    

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.12/typed.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const targetElement = document.getElementById("typewriter-content");
        const textToType = targetElement.innerHTML;

        targetElement.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the initial content

        const options = {
            strings: [textToType],
            typeSpeed: 10, // Adjust the speed (milliseconds per character) as needed
        };

        const typed = new Typed(targetElement, options);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```